# Reporting Services Configuration Manager is not connecting, it is integrated in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, report

I have a sharepoint 2010 portal with some dashboards and reports. No I have a permission problem, because I cannot view these reports.

I would like to have a look in Reporting Services Configuration Manager, but I cannot connect to the server where sharepoint and SQL server is installed. I enter the server name and press on find. It gives me the following error:

Unable to connect to the Report Server MYSERVERNAME.

By the way, I try to fix this problem:

> AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user
>   'Mydomain\MyUserAccount' are insufficient for performing this
>   operation.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably want to be using SharePoint Central Administration, not RS Configuration Manager.  Also, RS Configuration Manager isn't where you'd manage access to report objects.

That said:

- Try remoting into the host machine and running the tool locally on the server.
- Ensure the proper ports are open for you to be connecting remotely (and that they SHOULD be open - there are very valid security reasons to block them)
- Are you 100% certain you're connecting to the right address?  Is it possible the SSRS service itself is on a different machine than the Sharepoint service and the SQL server?